# Difference between fmt.Println() and println() in Go

Tags: go, println

As illustrated below, both `fmt.Println()` and `println()` give same output in Go: `Hello world!`

But: how do they differ from each other?

Snippet 1, using the [`fmt`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) package;

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello world!")
}
```

Snippet 2, without the `fmt` package;

```golang
package main

func main() {
    println("Hello world!")
}
```

Answer (score 174, accepted):

`println` is an built-in function (into the runtime) which may eventually be removed, while the `fmt` package is in the standard library, which will persist. See [the spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Bootstrapping) on that topic.

For language developers it is handy to have a `println` without dependencies, but the way to go is to use the `fmt` package or something similar (`log` for example).

As you can [see in the implementation](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/a1e9148e3dbb20a18e0139583e7d835cc7a820bf/src/runtime/print.go#L58) the `print(ln)` functions are not designed to even remotely support a different output mode and are mainly a debug tool.

Answer (score 151):

To build upon nemo's answer:

`println` is a function built into the language. It is in the Bootstrapping section of the [spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Bootstrapping). From the link:

> Current implementations provide several built-in functions useful
>   during bootstrapping. These functions are documented for completeness
>   but are not guaranteed to stay in the language. They do not return a
>   result.
>
> ```
> Function   Behavior
>
> print      prints all arguments; formatting of arguments is implementation-specific
> println    like print but prints spaces between arguments and a newline at the end
> ```

Thus, they are useful to developers, because they lack dependencies (being built into the compiler), but not in production code. It also important to note that `print` and `println` **report to `stderr`, not `stdout`**.

The family provided by `fmt`, however, are built to be in production code. They report predictably to `stdout`, unless otherwise specified. They are more versatile (`fmt.Fprint*` can report to any `io.Writer`, such as `os.Stdout`, `os.Stderr`, or even a `net.Conn` type.) and are not implementation specific.

Most packages that are responsible for output have `fmt` as a dependency, such as `log`. If your program is going to be outputting anything in production, `fmt` is most likely the package that you want.

Comment: "but not in production code" what does this mean? When I run `go build`, the output binary still has the text from `println`.

Comment: It just means that it should not be used in "important" code.  Production code is code that is used for some sort of larger project or product that a company or gov't agency uses.

In other words, it's fine for a homework assignment, but not for a software engineer who gets paid to do her job.

Answer (score 8):

I can see difference here:

rangeOverIntsAndStrings(1, 5)

```
func rangeOverIntsAndStrings(args ...interface{}) {
    for _, v := range args {
        println(v)
    }
}
```

// output

```
(0x108f060,0x10c5358)
(0x108f060,0x10c5360)
```

vs

```
func rangeOverIntsAndStrings(args ...interface{}) {
    for _, v := range args {
        fmt.Println(v)
    }
}
```

// output

```
1
5
```

Answer (score -1):

As for the difference, [this](https://play.golang.org/p/RW9yhffJ3W) is an example.

`println()` prints a pointer point to the address of function test.

`fmt.Println()` prints the address of function.

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to say.

Answer (score -1):

Interesting Example:

```golang
➜  netpoll git:(develop) ✗ cat test.go
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
        a := new(struct{})
        b := new(struct{})
        println(a, b, a == b)

        c := new(struct{})
        d := new(struct{})
        fmt.Printf("%v %v %v\n", c, d, c == d)
}
➜  netpoll git:(develop) ✗ go run test.go       
0xc000074f47 0xc000074f47 false
&{} &{} true
➜  netpoll git:(develop) ✗ go run -gcflags="-m" test.go
# command-line-arguments
./test.go:12:12: inlining call to fmt.Printf
./test.go:6:10: new(struct {}) does not escape
./test.go:7:10: new(struct {}) does not escape
./test.go:10:10: new(struct {}) escapes to heap
./test.go:11:10: new(struct {}) escapes to heap
./test.go:12:35: c == d escapes to heap
./test.go:12:12: []interface {} literal does not escape
<autogenerated>:1: .this does not escape
0xc000074f47 0xc000074f47 false
&{} &{} true
```

It is something difference between `println` and `fmt.Printf`.

Comment: Why you did not compare with `println` vs `fmt.Println` instead?