# HackerRank task Sales by Match doesn't pass tests

Tags: go

I solved [Sales by Match](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sock-merchant/problem?h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=warmup) problem in this way:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var amount int
    _, _ = fmt.Scanf("%d", &amount)

    pairs := 0
    set := make(map[int]bool)
    for i := 0; i < amount; i++ {
        var number int
        _, _ = fmt.Scanf("%d", &number)

        if set[number] {
            set[number] = false
            pairs++
        } else {
            set[number] = true
        }
    }
    println(pairs)
}
```

I tested it with the following input:

9
10 20 20 10 10 30 50 10 20

Here's the result:

[image]

So, as you can see, everything works fine. But when I run the tests I see the following result:

[image]

I don't understand why they are not passed, so, please, can anyone explain what's the problem in my solution? Thanks in advance I would appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `println(pairs)` to `fmt.Print(pairs)`because [println](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14680255/difference-between-fmt-println-and-println-in-go) writes to stderr and hackerrank looks at stdout for the result.